# setting linearlayout height does not work

Tags: android, xml

I have a listview inside a linear layout whose height is set as "WRAP_CONTENT", so the list is appearing inside the linear layout, when i populate the list, i attach some hidden list items within each list row, i want to show these items onListitemClick listner,

Everything is working fine,but if i have only one list child, then i have to scroll the view to see that layout that is visible now,
My question is:
I want to increase the height of that linear layout when the list item is clicked and and the view is visible..

here is xml..

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/listContainer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    //used this relative layout to set different backgroung for each time..     


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/listHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

When the hidden item is visible, then i use this code to increase height,

```
LayoutParams paramsLinearLayout;
    LinearLayout layoutContainer;
layoutContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listContainer);
    paramsLinearLayout =  layoutContainer.getLayoutParams();
    layoutContainer.setMinimumHeight(paramsLinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: Accept answer if that solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code :

```
LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(getContext());
LayoutParams linearParams=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,Height what you want);
```

instead of :

```
LayoutParams paramsLinearLayout;
    LinearLayout layoutContainer;
layoutContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listContainer);
    paramsLinearLayout =  layoutContainer.getLayoutParams();
    layoutContainer.setMinimumHeight(paramsLinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not have a view with height match_parent inside a layout with height wrap_content, as in your case:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/listContainer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    //used this relative layout to set different backgroung for each time..     

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Can't you set linearlayout's height to match_parent as well?